# Designing fact table with parent row IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

I've been working on my first data warehouse design, and came across a question which I wasn't able to find an answer for.

Every row in my fact table needs to identify the RowID of the "parent" record. In my case, every shipment event causes subsequent events to belong to that row. If the product is reshipped then the following ones belong to that new row and so forth.

However, it is possible for various reasons that not every product has a shipment history. Therefore making these rows null.

Each row in my fact table has a unique id so I can refer to it, but where should I store this relationship? Do I add in a nullable column to the fact table for ParentRowId? Do I create a factless fact table defining the relationship?

I'm leaning towards the first option, but was unsure what would be "proper" in this instance. Looking at about 3mil rows per year if that makes a difference on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: With 3m rows per year it seems performance and storage are not concerns of yours.

Comment: @usr be that as it may, I would still like to understand the correct way

Comment: I can't understand very well your example. Which is the grain of your fact table? It is a shipment? It is a shipment history? In any case a null key in a fact table is not "proper".

Comment: @mombo the grain is an event of a single unit (serial number). So a series of facts would be Shipment > Return > Shipment > Claim > Claim > Return > Shipment > Claim... 8 facts. Though as I said this is ideal as it is possible a Shipment does not exist, hence why a null would exist

Answer (score 0):

I have always built a separate table to do 'bridge tables', 'coverage tables' and things of that nature.  You are going to have to do a join anyways (a self join) to find the parent, and thus there is no harm in having that join to a table that has the responsibility of keeping that relationship.